# Why did rebase and hard reset give me different results?

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-rebase, git-reset

I have forked another repo to create pull requests for it. No one else is contributing to that repo during the period described here.

My first commits I submit as a pull request to the remote repo. This is accepted. My second pull request has errors that need fixing, but this requires reverting the files to a previous state as the issue is I broke formatting as my editor change them to a different format.

This would appear to be something I can use rebase for. However, when I use "git rebase upstream/master" while having my master branch checked out I am told "Current branch master is up to date." My branch is currently one commit ahead of upstream, and my understanding of rebase is that it should move HEAD on my branch to the last commit on the branch I'm rebasing against.

While [reading the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to see what I'd done wrong I noticed that "git reset --hard " was supposed to do the same thing. So I did "git reset --hard upstream/master" and this has the desired effect of moving HEAD to the accepted pull request of mine.

My question is that given both are supposed to do the same thing why did I get different results?

Comment: Nope, that's not what rebase does. It takes a commit you specify (remote HEAD or whatever) and _replays_ your local commits on top of it.

Comment: Read the DESCRIPTION section of `git help rebase` carefully. There are good examples there. `rebase` is not supposed to do the same as `reset --hard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I use "git rebase upstream/master" while having my master branch checked out I am told "Current branch master is up to date."

That would replay `master` on top of `upstream/master`, which means there is nothing to do, since `upstream/master` commits are already part of `master`.

Typically, when you submit a PR, you want to be sure those are done on top of the most up-to-date upstream master branch, meaning the updated original repo (which was forked)

```
git checkout my_PR_branch
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

This assume your PR is done in a branch instead of `master`.
If your PR was done on `master`, then:

- create a branch from your current `master`: `git branch mypr`; `git push -u origin mypr`; # make a new PR from that branch.
- reset your master to `origin/master`: `git fetch` and `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: But in this instance my master branch is one commit ahead of upstream/master. That commit has been submitted as a PR but not accepted. And if there is nothing for rebase to do why does a hard reset do something?

Comment: @Quitch Exactly: you need to rebase, then force push that branch to your fork: the PR will be updated.

Comment: @Quitch as for master, you can indeed reset it to upstream master. But the point is: we are talking about two different branches: one (for the PR) to be rebase, and one (master) to be reset.